# получение вероятности принадлежности к классу в sklearn

Tags: python

Собственно классификация данных методом логистической регрессии:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, [2,3]]
y = iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
                                X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0
                            )

sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(X_train)
X_train_std = sc.transform(X_train)
X_test_std = sc.transform(X_test)

lr = LogisticRegression(C=1000.0, random_state=0)
lr.fit(X_train_std, y_train)

lr.predict_proba([X_test_std[0,:]])
```

Тренировочные данные взяты прямо из библиотеки:

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()
```

Проблема в методе:

```
lr.predict_proba([X_test_std[0,:]])
```

который должен должен предсказывать вероятность принадлежности образца(ов) к имеющимся классам, и должен выдавать результат в таком виде:

```
array([[ 0.000, 0.063, 0.937 ]])
```

Приведенный выше массив должен говорить о том что модель предсказывает с шансом 93% принадлежность первого образца к третьему классу и 6.3% ко второму (к первому 0)
Но мне вместо этого выдает следующее:

```
array([[  2.05743774e-11,   6.31620264e-02,   9.36837974e-01]])
```

Как исправить, что не так ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже [сказал коллега @Applemoon](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/712409/211923) - вы получили правильные значения - просто они в виде `"scientific notation"`.

Вот пример:

```
In [91]: A = np.array([[  2.05743774e-11,   6.31620264e-02,   9.36837974e-01]])

In [92]: print(A)
[[  2.05743774e-11   6.31620264e-02   9.36837974e-01]]

In [93]: np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

In [94]: print(A)
[[ 0.          0.06316203  0.93683797]]
```

Comment: А можно это дело как то сократить до 4 знаков после запятой ?

Comment: formatter={'all':lambda x: round(x,4)} почему то не работает

Comment: все разобрался precision параметр )

Answer (score 1):

```
array([[ 0.000, 0.063, 0.937 ]])
```

и

```
array([[  2.05743774e-11,   6.31620264e-02,   9.36837974e-01]])
```

- это совершенно одни и те же числа, правда с разной точностью. 
Запись "e-02" у числа означает умножение на 10 в степени -2

Comment: Ну так и как мне получить в нужном виде ?